# Oracle Text - "user filter command exited with status 127"

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search, oracle-text

I'm trying to create full text index using oracle text module on table containing blobs (files).

I'm using following script to create an index..

```
CREATE INDEX my_docs_doc_idx ON test_blob(doc) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;
```

I got the result:

```
[SQL] CREATE INDEX my_docs_doc_idx ON test_blob(doc) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.190ms
```

However, when I want to test created index using...

```
SELECT SCORE(1) score, FILE_NAME FROM TEST_BLOB WHERE CONTAINS (doc,'cola',1) > 0
```

I always get 0 results, no matter what value I add to selector.

Thanks to article:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/434057?start=0&tstart=0 I found errors in ctx_user_index_errors table...

```
DRG-11207: user filter command exited with status 127
```

What could be a cause of this problem?

---

**EDIT:**

Issue seems to be connected with operation system.
Oracle installed on Windows indexes fine, while one installed on Redhat won't work at all.

Comment: you have `Affected rows: 0`, do you apply your index on empty table?

Comment: No, table is filled with 3 different entries with blob data in doc column + id, file_name and timestamp.

Comment: From the table name, is `test_blob.doc` a BLOB?

Comment: Yes, doc field is defined as BLOB type.

Answer (score 1):

Just worked through a similar "status 127" issue on linux. The default content filter, `CTXSYS.AUTO_FILTER`, uses a program to convert binary files to text. So I tried running the `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/ctx/bin/ctxhx` program and got a missing library error.

Running `yum install compat-libstdc++-33 libstdc++.so.5 -y` 
fixed the issue and Oracle will now search PDF files, perform markup on the search terms, and return results in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem.
Our Oracle Database version is 11.2.0.4.181016 after applying the patch "Patch 28204707: DATABASE PATCH SET UPDATE 11.2.0.4.181016" for Linux86-64.

We discovered that libraries for module ctx (Oracle Intermedia) used for indexing, see `CTXSYS.AUTO_FILTER` and `$ORACLE_HOME/ctx/bin/ctxhx`, were not for Linux86-64 but for Itanium IA-64, so for a different architecture. 
Just that single module was wrong.

When we tried to run the `$ORACLE_HOME/ctx/bin/ctxhx` the `libsc_ca.so` was not found but it was there.
So we cheked the `$ORACLE_HOME/ctx/lib/libsc_ca.so` with `readelf` utility.

```
readelf -h ctx/lib/libsc_ca.so
```

and we could find that it was for a wrong architecture.

We found Doc ID 2481631.1 on Oracle Support and following that we applied Patch 18121298 that solved us the problem.